# Python 3.9.9 - How to calculate the log of division of two items (t and t+1) from one array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, calculation

I've stumbled onto a simple problem that blocks me from any further progress.
I'd like to calculate the log of the division of two items in a loop and then save each result to a new array.

So I have my dataset that is already scaled with Sklearn MinMaxScaler, and the precise calculations I'd like to perform are these:

```
logs = np.empty(12530)
for i in data_prepared - 1:
    logs[i] = np.log10(data_prepared[i + 1] / data_prepared[i])
```

But both `math.log10()` and `np.log10` return Index Error:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

How can I perform the calculations I need?

EDIT:
data_prepared dtype is float32

Comment: `range(len(data_prepared)-1)`? Please provide a [mre]. Vectorized: `np.log10(data_prepared[1:] / data_prepared[:-1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data_prepared` is a `numpy.array()`, your loop will return the values of this list, not the indices. Your error hints that this is what is happening, since the values from `data_prepared` are not necessarily integers nor booleans.

```
for i in data_prepared - 1:
```

is the same as

```
for j in range(len(data_prepared)):
    i = data_prepared[j] - 1
```

So you should do

```
logs = np.empty(12530)
for i in range(len(data_prepared) - 1):
    logs[i] = np.log10(data_prepared[i + 1] / data_prepared[i])
```

Or use dot products as pointed out in the comments.